# Angular binding does not change

Tags: angularjs

i have this controller and this view (html).
if i give an initial value to $scope.article.Context, it will be shown in the view. (means
that the view recognizes the controller).
when i change the $scope.article.Context value inside a controller function, i dont see it changing in the view.
any idea ?
Thanks !!!

controller:

```
angular.module('generalApp', [])
    .controller('menuController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.article = {Context:"initial value"}  ;

        $scope.menuLinkSelected = function (articleId) {
            $http.post("Home/GetArticle?articleId=" + articleId).then(function (response) {
                $scope.article.Context = "new value";
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        };
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="generalApp">

<div ng-controller="menuController">
    <div ng-include="'partials/topMenu.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'partials/sideMenu.html'"></div>

    <div ng-model="article">
        <label>{{article.Context}}</label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="ziba()" />
</div>
```

Comment: You do not need the $scope.apply(). What you have should work. You do not need to set the ngModel on the div. What you have on the label should suffice. Like @Jake mentioned, are you sure your $http call is returning?

Comment: @moshi, did either of these answers end up working for you?

Comment: Hi. OK, I removed the $scope.$apply. About the $http call, yes, it returns value, but guys, look at this row - $scope.article.Context = "new value"; I even send a hard coded value. Even if there where no return from $http, i do return a value here....

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
<div>
   <label ng-bind="article.Context"></label>
</div>
```

You're `ng-model` doesn't do anything when you assign it to that `div`.

**JSFiddle :**

Here you have a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm95A/2/) using your example.

Comment: Hi, about writing ng-model inside the div, it should be ok, i have it working somewhere else like this. I just don't know what is the problem here... btw - article.Context won't solve it :-(  any other idea ? Thanks !!!

Comment: @moshi, hi. If you see my fiddle, your example works :) Maybe there are something else in your controller or view that causes it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your $http POST request is actually returning? You could test this by changing your controller to update $scope.article.Context like this:

```
var timerFn = function(){
  $scope.article.Context = "It works!";
};

$timeout(timerFn, 1000);
```

If that's the issue, you may want to try using this $http syntax to handle your POST request's callback:

```
$http.post('someUrl')
     .success(function(data, status){
       console.log(data);
     })
     .error(function(data, status){
       console.log(data);
     });
```

Sidenotes:

(1) You can probably just set your ng-model in the DOM to "article.Context" although what you have should work.

(2) You don't need to call $scope.$apply() inside of Angular. It's only used to update bindings when changes occur outside of Angular.

Comment: Hi, yes , the $scope.$apply() doesn't have to be there - my mistake. About the data coming or not,  so it comes, since I put an alert to verify. About the "article.Context", it doesn't do any change... any other idea ? Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you tried using another property name besides "Context"? As you can see from the blue formatting above, it appears to be a reserved keyword. (Although I've never heard of it or used it.) Could you try $scope.article.test123 instead of $scope.article.Context?